# fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken is not working in NODE

Tags: node.js, authentication, postman, passport-jwt

I did following things to passport authentication in Node.

1) I am using jwtFromRequest : `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()`,

```
module.exports = function(passport){
    var opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    console.log('Inside passport');
    //opts.issuer = 'accounts.examplesoft.com';
    //opts.audience = 'yoursite.net';
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        console.log('Payload :: '+jwt_payload._doc);
        User.getUserById({id: jwt_payload._doc._id}, function(err, User) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (User) {
                return done(null, User);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
                // or you could create a new account
            }
        });
    }));
```

2) Calling the method in the following way:

```
userExpressRoutes.route('/profile')
    .get(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function (req, res) {  });
```

3) Setting the header in Ppostman like : `Authorization:Bearer {token}`

[Post Authentication Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu2OV.png)

4) It is giving `undefined` payload

```
Payload :: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

What is missing here to get Jwt_payload?

Can someone help me?

Comment: User.getUserById({$**_id**: jwt_payload._doc._id}, function(err, User) {                       is it _id or id

Comment: @SanjaySinghBhandari I tried both id and _id , but it's not working

Comment: If you do `console.log('jwt_payload =', jwt_payload);`, what do you get? Maybe it should be `doc` instead of `_doc`, for example.

Comment: @DavidKnipe HI David, I am getting jwt_payload =undefined in console.That is the issue. I am getting undefined payload.

Comment: @SanketLathiya No you're not, you're getting `jwt_payload._doc = undefined`. If `jwt_payload` was undefined the error message would be "Cannot read property '_doc' of undefined".

Comment: HI All ,
I resolved by below code . Thanks for help.

Comment: module.exports = function(passport){
  let opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    User.findById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, User) => {
      if(err){
        return done(err, false);
      }

      if(User){
        return done(null, User);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by below code snippet. Thanks everyone for support...

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/User');
const config = require('../config/DB');

module.exports = function(passport){
  let opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    User.findById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, User) => {
      if(err){
        return done(err, false);
      }

      if(User){
        return done(null, User);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    });
  }));
}
```

Then In request headers pass token like this

```
Authorization:bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiQ2xpZW50IiwiX2lkIjoiNWUzN2NkMGI4YTAxNjEwNWNhMmFjZjYwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmFqYWt0YUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRzWXN4MGcyWGsybWdSTHNaZXBEYkV1MklRcGhVOURkNnczeTBHaUxMWHJVeW5aazlUR0xKSyIsIl9fdiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTgwNzE4NjQxLCJleHAiOjE1ODA3Mjg3MjF9.T8n1YWRSHfr_1caZ51TbT4VdnBx2uXg1x2JOJC-TBL0
```

Comment: I also added [ token: `Bearer ${token}` ] while generating token in code.

Answer (score 15):

### Some working Combinations

**For - fromHeader**

```
ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),

Authorization : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiQ2xpZW50IiwiX2lkIjoiNWUzN2NkMGI4YTAxNjEwNWNhMmFjZjYwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmFqYWt0YUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRzWXN4MGcyWGsybWdSTHNaZXBEYkV1MklRcGhVOURkNnczeTBHaUxMWHJVeW5aazlUR0xKSyIsIl9fdiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTgwNzE5ODE3LCJleHAiOjE1ODA3Mjk4OTd9.38x2wztqJWz9EH8_lN0ca-L-8mTQvW36iF2bfGk_ydg
```

**For - fromHeader**

```
ExtractJwt.fromHeader('HelloTom'),

HelloTom : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiQ2xpZW50IiwiX2lkIjoiNWUzN2NkMGI4YTAxNjEwNWNhMmFjZjYwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmFqYWt0YUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRzWXN4MGcyWGsybWdSTHNaZXBEYkV1MklRcGhVOURkNnczeTBHaUxMWHJVeW5aazlUR0xKSyIsIl9fdiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTgwNzE5ODE3LCJleHAiOjE1ODA3Mjk4OTd9.38x2wztqJWz9EH8_lN0ca-L-8mTQvW36iF2bfGk_ydg
```

**For - fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken**

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),

Authorization : bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiQ2xpZW50IiwiX2lkIjoiNWUzN2NkMGI4YTAxNjEwNWNhMmFjZjYwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmFqYWt0YUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRzWXN4MGcyWGsybWdSTHNaZXBEYkV1MklRcGhVOURkNnczeTBHaUxMWHJVeW5aazlUR0xKSyIsIl9fdiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTgwNzE5ODE3LCJleHAiOjE1ODA3Mjk4OTd9.38x2wztqJWz9EH8_lN0ca-L-8mTQvW36iF2bfGk_ydg
```

**For - fromAuthHeaderWithScheme**

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT'),

Authorization : JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiQ2xpZW50IiwiX2lkIjoiNWUzN2NkMGI4YTAxNjEwNWNhMmFjZjYwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmFqYWt0YUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRzWXN4MGcyWGsybWdSTHNaZXBEYkV1MklRcGhVOURkNnczeTBHaUxMWHJVeW5aazlUR0xKSyIsIl9fdiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTgwNzE5ODE3LCJleHAiOjE1ODA3Mjk4OTd9.38x2wztqJWz9EH8_lN0ca-L-8mTQvW36iF2bfGk_ydg
```

**For - fromAuthHeaderWithScheme**

```
ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('HelloJerry'),

Authorization : HelloJerry eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoiQ2xpZW50IiwiX2lkIjoiNWUzN2NkMGI4YTAxNjEwNWNhMmFjZjYwIiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmFqYWt0YUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRzWXN4MGcyWGsybWdSTHNaZXBEYkV1MklRcGhVOURkNnczeTBHaUxMWHJVeW5aazlUR0xKSyIsIl9fdiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTgwNzE5ODE3LCJleHAiOjE1ODA3Mjk4OTd9.38x2wztqJWz9EH8_lN0ca-L-8mTQvW36iF2bfGk_ydg
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

I changed Authorization Header in request from:
`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsI...` (jwt token)

to `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsI...`